# NSTextField's cell setPlaceholderAttributedString - placeholder not visible when got focus

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I do use `setPlaceholderAttributedString:` of `NSTextFieldCell` object to set placeholder with custom font and color. Here's the whole code ...

```
_statusMessageField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
[_statusMessageField setBordered:NO];
[_statusMessageField setBezeled:NO];
[_statusMessageField setFocusRingType:NSFocusRingTypeNone];
[_statusMessageField setDrawsBackground:NO];
[_statusMessageField setTextColor:TM_NS_COLOR(35, 37, 46)];
[_statusMessageField setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:13.0]];

NSMutableAttributedString *placeholder = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"What's up?"];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange( 0, [placeholder length] );
[placeholder addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:13.0] range:range];
[placeholder addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:TM_NS_COLORA( 92, 97, 114, 0.7 ) range:range];
[placeholder fixAttributesInRange:range];
[_statusMessageField.cell setPlaceholderAttributedString:placeholder];
_statusMessageField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self addSubview:_statusMessageField];
```

... and it drives me crazy, because ...

- placeholder is visible only if `NSTextField` has no focus,
- when I click on `NSTextField`, caret is visible, nothing entered yet, but placeholder disappears, which is wrong, should be visible until at least one character is entered,

... when I replace `setPlaceholderAttributedString:` with `setPlaceholderString:` (no attribution), placeholder behaves correctly - is visible when `NSTextField` has no focus or it has focus and nothing is entered yet.

Any idea what can be wrong?

Here's the link to the image http://d.pr/i/WoC9 where you can see the difference.

Comment: You've set the frame size to `NSZeroRect`?

Comment: Setting the TextField's text to nil or the empty string, @"" will cause the placeholder text to be displayed. NSTextFieldCell implements setPlaceholderString, and NSTextField in turn has an embedded NSTextFieldCell. I was setting a NSTextField's contents to empty using [textField setStringValue:@""].

Comment: @trojanfoe yep, it's normally visible, because I do use auto layout constraints.

Comment: @parilogic NSTextField's text is empty.

Comment: Did edit question and added screenshot to show the difference between attributed and non attributed placeholder string. http://d.pr/i/WoC9

Comment: @RobertVojta were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope. I did use custom component with custom placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the box "Refuses First Responder" in state of NSTextField.

This will solve the problem.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    [_statusMessageField setBordered:NO];
    [_statusMessageField setBezeled:NO];
    [_statusMessageField setFocusRingType:NSFocusRingTypeNone];
    [_statusMessageField setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [_statusMessageField setTextColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
    [_statusMessageField setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:13.0]];

    NSMutableAttributedString *placeholder = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"What's up?"];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange( 0, [placeholder length] );
    [placeholder addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:13.0] range:range];
    [placeholder addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[NSColor greenColor] range:range];
    [placeholder fixAttributesInRange:range];
    [_statusMessageField.cell setPlaceholderAttributedString:placeholder];
    _statusMessageField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [_statusMessageField setRefusesFirstResponder:NO];


}

- (void)awakeFromNib {

    [_statusMessageField setRefusesFirstResponder:YES];
}
```

Regards,
Neelam

Comment: Nope, this doesn't solve the issue. And also I do not want to refuse first responder.

Comment: But it works well for me . I created new project with your code. It works with above changes

Comment: But when I set refuses first responder to YES, text field is not counted in a loop where I can jump between controls via tab key for example and I'm forced to use mouse click.

Comment: You can set "Refuses First Responder" to NO afterwards.

Comment: UPdated the code above .. this works for jumping btw controls via tab .. take a look

Comment: You're right, it sometimes does work. But this is kind of workaround, because it has nothing to do with first responder. Should work in the same way as non attributed placeholder. Anyway, thanks for your time.